# Opencart https url principal

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

activate the security certificate in the store, it works well but is still the main url http and not https, and change the url in the config.php, when a product is entered if https appears or when the logo is clicked.

I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I did the following:

into de .httacces file write this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

this is all.